# Identify Midp 2.0 vs Midp 2.1 vs Android

Tags: php, android, wap, midp-2.0

How do I differentiate between Midp 2.0 and 2.1 and Android from a WAP browser so as to redirect them to different location to download the app corresponding to their mobile.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty difficult to catch all cases correctly, and anyone can always just set their User-Agent to a different value, but the general way to do it in `php` is:

1. Automatically, with [`get_browser()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), which requires an up-to-date version of [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/downloads.asp)

   ```
   $browserInfo = get_browser();
   if($browserInfo->platform === "Android")
   {
       // deliver Android link
   } else if($browserInfo->platform === "JAVA") { // MIDP
       // deliver MIDP link
   }
   ```
2. Manually, by running a bunch of regex strings against `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`. Very generic matches could be done on `.*MIDP.*` and `.*Android.*` if you want to do it this way.

   ```
   if(preg_match("/.*Android.*/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) // Android
   {
        // deliver Android link
   } else if(preg_match("/.*MIDP.*/", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { // MIDP
        // deliver MIDP link
   }
   ```